# How to get the correct pivoting for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have following `pandas` DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'nombreNumeroUnico': ['UP2_G1_B', 'UP2_G2_B'],
    'pMax': [110.0, 110.0]
})

df2
((Out  [1])): 
  nombreNumeroUnico   pMax
0          UP2_G1_B  110.0
1          UP2_G2_B  110.0
```

### Expected result

I want to transform this into:

```
   UP2_G1_B  UP2_G2_B
0       110       110
```

### What I have tried so far

So far I was able to convert it using pivot function but I am not getting the exact result I want.

```
df2.pivot(index=None, columns="nombreNumeroUnico", values="pMax")
((Out  [57])): 
nombreNumeroUnico  UP2_G1_B  UP2_G2_B
0                     110.0       NaN
1                       NaN     110.0
```

### Question

But it's not the exact result I want. How can I get the expected result?

Comment: have you tried the `pivot_table` method?

Comment: Thanks @stevev , I posted an answer using this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls use `df2.set_index('nombreNumeroUnico').T.reset_index(drop=True)`

Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'nombreNumeroUnico': ['UP2_G1_B', 'UP2_G2_B'],
    'pMax': [110.0, 110.0]
})

result_df = df2.set_index('nombreNumeroUnico').T.reset_index(drop=True)
result_df.columns.name = None
print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
   UP2_G1_B  UP2_G2_B
0     110.0     110.0
```

Comment: Of course. Transpose function was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be:

```
df = df2.pivot_table(columns="nombreNumeroUnico", values="pMax")
df.columns.name = None
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then:

```
df
((Out  [84])): 
   UP2_G1_B  UP2_G2_B
0     110.0     110.0
```